How to stream a local video to virtual webcam using ffmpeg?
I created the virtual camera "abdullah". How to use ffmpeg to steam that local video trial_video.mp4 to the virtual camera?
I am using windows 11.

I’m voting to close this question because this is specifically about operation of something OS-specific on an OS that is neither UNIX nor Linux.
